# Prove nontrivial topological properties

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

Let $C$ be a compact set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ with the following property:

for any $\varepsilon> 0$ there exists a  finite number $M(=M(\varepsilon))$ of open balls $B_i$ with radius   $r_i$, $i\in\{1,\ldots,M\}$ s. t.
$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{M}B_i \supset C $
and

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M} r_i \leqslant \varepsilon $

Prove the following :

(1) for $n \geqslant  2 \; \Bbb{R}^n \setminus C$ is connected

(2) for $n \geqslant 3 \;\Bbb{R}^n\setminus C$ is simply connected   (I mean by that it has trivial fundamental group)

The only thing I was able to try were proof by contradiction or trying to understand intuitively how this space is made  but I did not conclude . 
In particular , I tried this:

for $\varepsilon > 0$ call $S_{\varepsilon }$ the finite cover of $C$ made by a finite number of balls whose sum of radii is less or equal than $\varepsilon$,say it $\{B_{i}^{\varepsilon}\}_{i=1}^{M(\varepsilon)},$which exists by hypotesis.
 I noticed that, since $C$ is closed , if a point $x$ does not belong to $C$ , then 
$L=\operatorname{dist}(x,C)  >  0$ . Choosing a cover of $C$ of the form $S_{\varepsilon } $ for $\varepsilon < L$ and assuming that every element of $S_{\varepsilon }$ intersects nontrivially $C$, I can argue that $x \notin B_i^\varepsilon $ for any $i$.
Otherwise, there would be a point $y$ in $C$ s. t. $\operatorname{dist}(x,y)< L$ which is not possible.

Define $A_{\varepsilon}= \bigcup\limits _{i=1}^{M(\varepsilon)} B_i^\varepsilon$.From what said, if I consider a small enough $\varepsilon$,then $x \notin A_{\varepsilon }$. Choosing $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{i}$ for $i \in \Bbb{N}$  from what  said  I could argue that

$\mathbb{R}^n \setminus C = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}^n\setminus A_{\frac{1}{i}})$

Manipulating a bit  this equality (not straightforward ) ,if, for example I may prove that $\exists j \geqslant 1 $ s. t.  $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A_{\frac{1}{k}}$ is  connected for any $k \geqslant j$, I may easily get point (1). Anyway I do not see how to prove it. I do not even see clearly if my previous observations are correct.

REMARK: Someone suggested this set is discrete , I think that this not set is necessarily discrete: If I take $C=\{(\frac{1}{n},0) \cup {(0,0)}\}$ ,$n \in \mathbb{N}$,and choose $\epsilon > 0$ I can find a cover of $C$ according to the hypotesis:

Choose a ball centered in $(0,0)$ of radius less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. You are left to cover a finite number $M$ of points. For any point,choose a open ball centered in itself with radius less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$. Formally you can do it because a point has a zero lebesgue measure and you can cover it with a ball of any radius you want. This cover respects the hypotesis.

Since I found in a standard topology exercise set ,its solution should not require big  machinery, so I would really appreciate a solution of this kind. In particular, it is a exercise from an admission test to a fourth year of universiy, so I assume  it is possible to use standard general topology(from a university course), fundamental groups, universal convering and homology.Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first one, matybe you can try to prove first that for any finite union of balls, $\mathbb R^n$ minus this union is connected, for $n\geq 2$ ? And for the second one, do the same for simple-connectedness and $n\geq 3$ ? Then understand how to use the hypothesis to go from there to $\mathbb R^n \setminus C$

Comment: I tried but I do not think  statement is  necessary true:  try  to cover by a finite union of balls(why not) the boundary of a circle in the euclidean plane .

Comment: The unit circle does not obey this property. So the statement says nothing about it.

Comment: I am editing the post so I will explain my attempt in this way properly

Comment: Could you tell us more context for this problem so we know what tools you have available? You have to show something is simply-connected, so do you have any results about the fundamental group?

Comment: I think you mean "radius" instead of "rays".

Comment: For (1), let $x,y \notin C$, consider the straight line segment connecting $x$ and $y$. Take a cover $S^{\varepsilon}$ of $C$ with sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. If the segment intersects $S^{\varepsilon}$, you can replace every subinterval within a covering ball by a curve on the boundary of that ball, leading to a path from $x$ to $y$ within $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus S^{\varepsilon} \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus C$. But I'm afraid filling in the details to get a complete proof is rather tedious.

Comment: How do you overcome the case in which some balls intersect at the boundary? I mean, why is it not possible the case that balls intersect in such a nontrivial way that it is not possible to do what you suggested? Thanks in advanced

Comment: It isn't possible that they intersect that badly (if $\varepsilon$ is small enough) because there are only finitely many balls, so the boundary of the union is still simple. But proving that would be a nightmare, I think. However, I believe I've found a simpler argument. By considering a plane through $x$ and $y$ we may assume $n = 2$, which makes the geometry simpler. Also, view the plane as $\mathbb{C}$, assume (by a change of coordinates) $x=0$, $y=1$. There is $d>0$ such that both points have distance $>d$ from $C$. If we have a disc $D=D_r(z_0)$ disjoint from $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant r$,

Comment: then $\lvert \arg w_1 - \arg w_2\rvert \leqslant 2r/d$ for all $w_1,w_2 \in D$. Thus if we pick $\varepsilon < \pi d$ there is a ray emanating from $0$ that doesn't intersect any of the discs. The same argument yields a ray emanating from $1$ not intersecting the discs. Connect the rays on the circle of radius $R$ ($R$ large enough, which is possible since $C$ is bounded).

Comment: I really appreciate this, but I need some clearance: I think you are trying to say that ,if I consider the origin of the complex plane and I consider a circle of radius $r$ centered in the origin, it is not possible that $C$ disconnects the origin and the boundary of the circle.So the complementary of $C$ is path connected "at the infinity" Anyhow I have a few things unclear:what do you mean by $z_0$, and what do you mean saying that if we have a disc disjoint from $|z| \leq r$, so $ |arg w_1-arg w_2| \leq \frac{2r}{d}$ . In particular, how geometrically do you exactly show the statement above

Comment: $z_0$ is an arbitrary point outside $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant d$. The centres of the discs covering $C$ will be used as $z_0$ (and $r_i$ as the radius $r$ of the disc $D = D_r(z_0)$). We can, by dropping discs not intersecting $C$ from the covering, guarantee that for small enough $\varepsilon$ none of the covering discs intersects $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant d$ or $\lvert z-1\rvert \leqslant d$. And keeping them a safe distance from $0$ and $1$ means that the ratio of the length of the argument-interval occupied by a disc and its radius remains bounded, with the bound depending only on $d$.

Comment: One can see that analytically: $$\lvert \arg w_1 - \arg w_2\rvert \leqslant \lvert \log w_1 - \log w_2\rvert = \biggl\lvert \int_{w_2}^{w_1} \frac{dz}{z}\biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{\lvert w_1 - w_2\rvert}{d}\,,$$ because $\lvert 1/z\rvert \leqslant 1/d$ on the segment between $w_1$ and $w_2$. Thus a disc with radius $\rho$ outside $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant d$ occupies an argument-interval of length at most $\frac{2\rho}{d}$. All covering discs together therefore obscure at most an angle of $\frac{2\varepsilon}{d}$.

Comment: This is so good I  thank you so much for this observation . If you ever take pleasure to help also in part 2 , It would be very much appreciated .